# Using Resque and resque_mailer to send emails raises Routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I'm trying to send emails using a background job in Rails 3 using Resque and the resque_mailer gem. Emails are sent fine when not using Resque, but when they are processed as a background job, the job fails raising a `ActionView::Template::Error` which I've traced back to a link that I'm trying to print on the email. This is the conflicting line:

```
link_to t('.here'), topic_url(@comment.topic, :load_all => true, :anchor => "c#{@comment.id}")
```

Even trying to print a `root_url` raises a similar exception.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is failing? I've tried almost everything :(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: On a side note, the `@comment` object is valid, so the error is not there :)

Comment: Another weird symptom, this works `link_to t('.here'), topic_url(:controller => "topics", :action => "show", :id => @comment.topic.id, :load_all => true, :anchor => "c#{@comment.id}")` while this doesn't `link_to t('.here'), topic_url(@comment.topic, :load_all => true, :anchor => "c#{@comment.id}")`

Comment: Did you find any solution to your problem. I am currently facing the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I'm assuming the error was a bug on rails that was later fixed, but I don't really know, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't send ActiveRecord objects in the params to the mailer method.
But rather send identifiers and load them in the method body.

Comment: This might be the problem. Another possibility is that you are passing a HashWithIndifferentAccess as a parameter to a Mailer method, which is then purely a Hash when sent to Resque and then retrieved. I've noticed that even if it's just a regular Hash with symbolic keys, they get converted to string keys by Resque.